# Access to screen denied error in screen share

Tags: sdk, access-denied, agora.io

I'm trying to have a video chat and screen sharing option using web SDK for Agora.io, but every time I try I get this error.

```
Media Error "Access to screen denied."
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your web browser do not have the right to access. Try their [test page](https://webdemo.agora.io/agora_webrtc_troubleshooting/) first.

Comment: Screen-sharing is natively supported by Firefox and latest Chrome but not Safari.